# Очистка данных о посещении сайта AngleSharp

Tags: c#, парсер, anglesharp

Использую библиотеку AngleSharp для работы с сайтом. На сайте стоит защита от частых запросов. Переделал свою программу под работу с прокси, но даже частая смена прокси не дает результатов.

То есть у меня есть несколько учетных записей и даже если я зайду на другую учетную запись под другим IP, после бана первой учетки, то мгновенно ограничат доступ к странице, но уже на новой учетной записи.

Как я понял (по аналогии с браузером, например Chrome) скорей всего остается история посещения куки итд. Так вот мне нужно как-то удалять все эти сведения перед сменой IP и входом под другой учетной записью.

Пример:
Например если использовать хром с vpn и не почистить историю посещения сайта, то тоже самое происходит (мгновенное ограничение доступа), а если перед входом под новым прокси очистить историю посещения сайта, то все ок.

Меня интересует следующий вопрос, как очистить историю действий на сайте если я использую AngleSharp?